# Como ajustar este boton para alinearlo bien con los demas objetos de la lista?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe alguna propiedad de html o css para hacer el ajuste bien?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
  }

  .nav > li {
    float:left;
  }

  .nav li a {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 12px;
    display:block;
  }

  .nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#0c6ab0 !important;
     border:6px solid #0c6ab0 !important;

  }
  .nav li a{
     border:2.5px solid #0c6ab0 !important;
  }
  .nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
  }

  .nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
  }

  .nav li ul li a {
    position:relative;
    right: 7% !important;
    border:2px solid #0c6ab0 ;
    color:#fff !important;

  }
  .nav li ul li a {
    border:2px solid #131415 !important;

  }
  .nav ul li ul li{
      position:relative !important;
  }

  .nav ul li ul li{
      right: 0px !important;
      top:0px !important;
  }
  .alinea{
 padding: 10px;


  }
```

`introducir el código

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="barra">
    <div class="contenedor clearfix">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/logo.svg" Style= "position:absolute;left:20px; top:0px; width:90px; height:90px;">
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-movil">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>

           <nav class="navegacion-principal clearfix">
            <div class="mover">
            <a href="servicio.php">Formulario</a>
            <a href="conferencia.html">Registros</a>
            <a href="calendario.html">Excel</a>
            <a href="invitados.html">Facturas y tickets</a>
             <ul class="nav margen"><li> <a href="registro.html">Agendas</a>
             <ul>
                <li> <a class="va" href="registro.html">Vehiculos</a></li>
                <li> <a href="registro.html">Proveedores</a></li>
             </ul></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <!--.contenedor-->
</div>
```

```
            </div>
            <!--.informacion-evento-->

        </div>
    </div>

    <!--.hero-->
</header>
```

`

Comment: podrías compartir tu codigo?

Comment: listo disculp, mi error

Comment: No pongas el HTML como foto, ponlo en texto como hiciste con el CSS.

Comment: agrega el código como texto no como imagen

Comment: el que quieres que se aline es Agendas ?

Comment: quiero alinear la lista que sale de agenda y bajar las pestañas del nav

Comment: Le aconsejo que edite su pregunta y sea lo mas explícito posible, además de publicar el código completo, de no ser así, será muy difícil ayudarlo. Probablemente su problema sea muy fácil de solucionar pero al no explicarse con claridad no podremos entenderlo.

Comment: Yo te aconsejo que edites tu pregunta y que proporciones más detalles de tu problema para que podamos solucionarlo mejor